# Cerrar menú emergente al hacer click fuera del mismo

Tags: javascript

El código permite abrir un menú emergente el hacer click en el enlace MENÚ, también permite cerrar dicho menú al hacer click de nuevo en el enlace MENÚ y en los enlaces dentro

El HTML contiene a la izquierda una sección donde iría una imagen, como el logotipo de la empresa y a la derecha un enlace, que permite abrir el menú emergente.

El código CSS permite ubicar correctamente cada elemento y darle estilos a los mismos.

EL código de Javascript tiene la función de abrir y cerrar el menú emergente al hacer click en el enlace MENÚ.

```js
//objeto con las propiedades del menu Movil
var propMenu = {
    burger_menu: document.getElementById('burger_menu'),
    slideMenu: document.getElementById('slideMenu'),
    menu_activo: false,
    elem_menu: document.querySelectorAll('#slideMenu .menu-principal a')
}



//objeto con los metodos del menu Movil
var metMenu = {
    
    inicio: function(){
        propMenu.burger_menu.addEventListener('click', metMenu.toggleMenu);
                
        for (var i = 0; i < propMenu.elem_menu.length; i++){
            propMenu.elem_menu[i].addEventListener('click', metMenu.ocultarMenu);
        }
        
        
    },
    
    toggleMenu: function(){
        if(propMenu.menu_activo == false){
            propMenu.menu_activo = true;
            propMenu.menu_activo_aux = true;
            propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className + ' active';
        }else{
            propMenu.menu_activo = false;
            propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className.replace('active', '');
        }
    },
    
    ocultarMenu: function(){
        propMenu.menu_activo = false;
        propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className.replace('active', '');
    },
    
    
}

metMenu.inicio();
```

```css
  header .menu-bar-movil {
    padding: 0 2.25rem;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 5.876rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .logo {
      max-width: 3.125rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .burger-menu {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 2.1875rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 5.875rem;
      left: -100%;
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1.25rem 2.25rem;
      width: 80%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu.active {
        left: 0; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .top-redes {
        margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
        header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .top-redes a {
          padding: 0 0.5625rem; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .menu-principal a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.625rem 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; }
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="menu-bar-movil">
            <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
            <div class="burger-menu" id="burger_menu">MENU</div>
            <div class="slideMenu" id="slideMenu">
                <div class="top-redes">
                    <a href="#">F</a>
                    <a href="#">T</a>
                    <a href="#">I</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu-principal">
                    <a href="#portada" class="smoothScroll">Inicio</a>
                    <a href="#nosotros" class="smoothScroll">Nosotros</a>
                    <a href="#chef" class="smoothScroll">Nuestro Chef</a>
                    <a href="#nuestro-menu" class="smoothScroll">Menú</a>
                    <a href="#contacto" class="smoothScroll">Contacto</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
</body>
```

EL problema se presenta cuando hago click fuera de dicho Menú emergente, en cualquier parte de la pagina, deseo cerrarlo al hacer click afuera pero no encuentro solución.

Answer (score 0):

A través de la función `contains` atachada al `document` podemos detectar si se ha hecho un `click` a determinado elemento dentro de nuestra Web.

Sabiendo esto añadí un escuchador de eventos al `document` para que en caso de hacer un `click` en cualquier sitio de la página se llame a la función `ocultarMenu` y dentro de esta contemplar que si el `click` se produjo fuera del elemento con clase `menu-bar-movil` entonces se proceda con la ocultación.

```js
//objeto con las propiedades del menu Movil
var propMenu = {
    burger_menu: document.getElementById('burger_menu'),
    slideMenu: document.getElementById('slideMenu'),
    menu_activo: false,
    elem_menu: document.querySelectorAll('#slideMenu .menu-principal a')
}



//objeto con los metodos del menu Movil
var metMenu = {
    
    inicio: function(){
        propMenu.burger_menu.addEventListener('click', metMenu.toggleMenu);
        document.addEventListener('click', metMenu.ocultarMenu);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < propMenu.elem_menu.length; i++){
            propMenu.elem_menu[i].addEventListener('click', metMenu.ocultarMenu);
        }
    },
    
    toggleMenu: function() {
        if(propMenu.menu_activo == false){
            propMenu.menu_activo = true;
            propMenu.menu_activo_aux = true;
            propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className + ' active';
        }else{
            propMenu.menu_activo = false;
            propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className.replace('active', '');
        }
    },
    
    ocultarMenu: function() {
        let click_dentro = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-bar-movil')[0].contains(event.target);

        if (!click_dentro) {
           propMenu.menu_activo = false;
           propMenu.slideMenu.className = propMenu.slideMenu.className.replace('active', '');
        }
    },
    
    
}

metMenu.inicio();
```

```css
header .menu-bar-movil {
    padding: 0 2.25rem;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 5.876rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .logo {
      max-width: 3.125rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .burger-menu {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 2.1875rem; }
    header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 5.875rem;
      left: -100%;
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1.25rem 2.25rem;
      width: 80%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu.active {
        left: 0; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .top-redes {
        margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
        header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .top-redes a {
          padding: 0 0.5625rem; }
      header .menu-bar-movil .slideMenu .menu-principal a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.625rem 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; }
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="menu-bar-movil">
            <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
            <div class="burger-menu" id="burger_menu">MENU</div>
            <div class="slideMenu" id="slideMenu">
                <div class="top-redes">
                    <a href="#">F</a>
                    <a href="#">T</a>
                    <a href="#">I</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu-principal">
                    <a href="#portada" class="smoothScroll">Inicio</a>
                    <a href="#nosotros" class="smoothScroll">Nosotros</a>
                    <a href="#chef" class="smoothScroll">Nuestro Chef</a>
                    <a href="#nuestro-menu" class="smoothScroll">Menú</a>
                    <a href="#contacto" class="smoothScroll">Contacto</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
</body>
```